# SpriteVisualElement doesn't take mouse input

Tags: apache-flex, click, mouse, sprite

I'm trying to use one great example of using SpriteVisualElement for item renderers from [**here:**](http://www.asfusion.com/blog/entry/mobile-itemrenderer-in-actionscript-part-4)

The issue i have is it's **impossible to detect the mouse click event when click points to the area of the renderer which doesn't have any child components**. For example: if I click on the textfield, then it works and i see the mouse even dispatched. If I click on an empty spot on the renderer then no mouse event is dispatched. I've tried mouseEnabled=true (which is true by default any way) with no luck. I see from the [**Flex doc:**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html)

the click event is inherited from InteractiveObject. So maybe this has something to do with the focus (see the tread at the and of the page). Looking for an explanation why InteractiveObject behaves that way. Thanks!

Comment: I just found if I fill the SpriteVisualElement with the color like so:    this.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff,0);
   this.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 40); 
   this.graphics.endFill();                                   then the filled area takes the mouse input. I'm still not getting the idea for such behavior, though.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you do not have anything in the renderer to click on so click will fall through your renderer, by adding and image or graphic you are creating a clickable area.
The best thing to do is to tell the render that it does not have any mouseChildren which will then make it respond to any click on it.

change this method

```
  public function TweetRenderer()
  {
     this.mouseChildren = false;
     percentWidth = 100;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks asMan, tried what you've suggested and it's still the same behavior.

Comment: Ah sorry I only looked at the code briefly as it seems to be a cluster. I assumed TweetRenderer would be the spot to put it. I don't have time right now to look at it but that should be the fix you need. You just need to find were to put it.

Answer (score 1):

I think is getting a bit clear now. The mouseChildren is a property on DisplayObjectContainer. And as the following example shows DisplayObjectContainer doesn't dispatch any mouse click events, when click occur on the area which is not taken by any of it's children. This is unintuitive because DisplayObjectContainer has a click event inherited from InteractiveObject, so one (a newbe like me) would expect it to dispatch an event if i click on the container. Setting mouseChildren=false kind of flattens the DisplayObjectContainer, so the click event on any of the children will be dispatched having target as a container. But!!! This still assumes that you click on the child, not on the empty area. There is no way to dispatch it when click is done inside the area which is not taken by the child. This example shows this: If you click on either TextField or on fill, then even is dispatched with SpriteVisualElement as target. If you click elsewhere the event is not dispatched. I'm still unclear on why this is an intended behavior, taking into account the presence of click event on the DisplayObjectContainer. Maybe because containers don't meant to detect the mouse clicks at all, but rather their children are? This is a bit unintuitive to me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)" >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
                var tf:TextField = new TextField();
                tf.text = "I'm inside SpriteVisualElement!";
                tf.background = true;
                tf.backgroundColor = 0xff0000;
                tf.alpha = 0.75;
                tf.selectable = false;
                tf.width = 150;
                tf.height = 25;
                uic.addChild(tf);
                uic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
                uic.mouseChildren = false;
                uic.mouseEnabled = true;

                uic.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
                uic.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
                uic.graphics.lineTo(uic.width,0);
                uic.graphics.lineTo(uic.width,uic.height);
                uic.graphics.lineTo(0,uic.height);
                uic.graphics.lineTo(0,0);  

                uic.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00,1);
                uic.graphics.drawRect(12, 12, 178, 28); 
                uic.graphics.endFill(); 

            }

            protected function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
                trace("click detected, target:",e.target);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:SpriteVisualElement id="uic" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" width="200" height="50" />
</s:Application>
```